# Which clustering algorithm should i choose

Tags: python-3.x

I am seeking a recommendation of an algorithm for clustering. I'm trying to cluster items from a store inventory (inventory length = 35'000 items) based on their description (string format).
After the text pre processing phase I proceed as follows:

- I tokenize the text (word_tokenize from nltk.tokenize);
- I create a dictionary (gensim.corpora.Dictionary);
- From the dictionary a create a corpus with doc2bow;
- Then I create a TfidfModel with gensim.models from corpus;
- Finally I create a similarity matrix with gensim Similarity;

When I'm trying to run a clustering model (AgglomerativeClustering) on the similarity matrix it runs from hours and did not finish. The matrix's dimension is 35kx35k floats.

Is there any other approach to perform this clustering problem without hitting the curse of dimensionality?

Thanks.

Example code:

```
data['Product'] = data.apply(lambda row: preprocess_text_prod(row['Product']), axis = 1)
gen_docs = [[w for w in word_tokenize(text)] for text in data['Product']]
dictionary = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(gen_docs)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(gen_doc) for gen_doc in gen_docs]
tf_idf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus)
sims_description = gensim.similarities.Similarity('./data/',tf_idf[corpus], num_features=len(dictionary))
sims = np.multiply(sims_factors, sims_description)#please ignore this line
del sims_factors, sims_description
gc.collect()
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
clustering = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters = None,
  compute_full_tree = True, distance_threshold = 0.25).fit(sims)
z = clustering.labels_
```